# Laravel trait saving event is fired on database query

Tags: php, laravel, traits

In my code, I created a trait to clear out some cache. It's code looks like below.

```
<?php 

namespace App\Models\Traits;

use App\Classes\Utilities\ResponseCache as ResponseCache;

trait ClearsResponseCache {
    public static function bootClearsResponseCache() {
        static::saving(function () {
            ResponseCache::removeAll();    
        });

        static::updating(function () {
            ResponseCache::removeAll();
        });

        static::deleting(function () {
            ResponseCache::removeAll();
        });
    }
}
```

In my controller I have a custom query to select some rows from the database.

```
public function fetchAllItems() {
    $items = DB::select('My custom query');    
    
    return response()->json($items);
}
```

Now, when this function is run, the saving event of ClearsResponseCache is fired, leading to my cache being deleted. Any idea why that event is being fired?

Comment: Are you using ResponseCache of your own? and you can use the telescope to investigate the request.

Comment: what is ResponseCache?

Comment: Presumably that trait goes in models. `DB::select` will not trigger any model events on its own. You can add something like a `dd(debug_backtrace())` to the trait methods to see where the call is actually coming from